# pyspark hive.table not reading all row of hive table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using hive llap(https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/spark-llap) in pyspark to read hive internal table like this:

```
df = hive.table(<tableName>)
```

But the issue is that my table has 18 million records, but when I do

```
df.count()
```

I just get 7.5 million as count which is wrong

Comment: did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to refresh spark metastore which does not utilize the hive metastore and the stats might be just stale

You can refresh the pyspark metastore like this :

```
spark.sql("REFRESH TABLE <TABLE_NAME>")
```